# Почему не преобразуется к строке?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты

```js
function makeBuffer() {
    let str = '';
    return function(...rest) {
        if (rest.length === 0) {
            return str;
        }
        str += rest;
        str.toString();
    };
};
;(function () {
  let buffer;
  beforeEach(function() {
    buffer = makeBuffer();
  });
  
  it("приводит всё к строке", function() {
    buffer(null);
    buffer(false);
    assert.equal(buffer(), "nullfalse");
  });
})()


var buffer = makeBuffer();

buffer('Расстояние');
buffer(' до');
buffer(' Луны');

console.log(buffer());
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://js.cx/test/libs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, при приведении массива, содержащего `null` в качестве элементов, вместо строки `"null"` вы получаете пустую строку:

```
console.log('' === ('' + [null])); // true
console.log(',' === ('' + [null, null])); // true
```

Происходит это потому, что метод [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) (который фактически вызывается для приведения массива к строке) преобразует `null` и `undefined` в [пустую строку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Description).

Как следствие, вместо автоматического преобразования массива в строку:

```
str += rest;
```

Вам следовало бы обрабатывать элементы массива `rest` вручную:

```
function makeBuffer() {
    let str = '';
    return function(...rest) {
        if (rest.length === 0) {
            return str;
        }
        str += rest.map(item => '' + item);
    };
};
```

**Замечание**

Еще более любопытные результаты вы получили бы, если бы скормили вашей исходной функции `buffer` более одного аргумента:

```
buffer('Расстояние');
buffer(' до', ' Луны');
console.log(buffer()); // "Расстояние до, Луны"
```

Этот факт тоже очевиден, если вспомнить, что для прведения массива к строке используется [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) без аргументов.

Comment: понял) спасибо)